# Clicking on a radio button changes other buttons styling if they have the same text

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am doing a React Quiz based on the OpenTrivia Api, I can't figure out an way to make that only the button that you click changes it's styling, for example if there are multiple true or false questions, if I click, all the other question answers will also change the styling. That doesn't happen with any other questions, only if the answers have the exact same text, so a true or false or multiple color option for example. I've set the opacity of the radio button to zero.

[image: Example]

**This is the React code**

```
function answerStyle(str) {
        if (props.gameState == "finished") {
            if (str == props.correctAnswer) {
                return "correct-markedAnswer";
            }        
        }
    }

const answersElem = answerArr.map(answer => (
        <div key={answer}>
            <input 
                type="radio" 
                id={`${props.question} ${answer}`} 
                name={props.question} 
                value={answer}
                checked={props.markedAnswers.includes(answer)} 
                onChange={props.onChange}/>
            <label htmlFor={`${props.question} ${answer}`} className={`${answerStyle(answer)}`}>{fixText(answer)}</label>
        </div>))
```

**CSS Code**

```
input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

label {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #2187ab;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-color: #2187ab;
    background-color: #2187ab;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.correct-markedAnswer {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-color: #2eb82e;
    background-color: #2eb82e;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the checked value in this, removing it solved the problem.

```
        <div key={`${props.question} ${answer}`}>
            <input 
                type="radio" 
                id={`${props.question} ${answer}`} 
                name={props.question} 
                value={answer}
                checked={props.markedAnswers.includes(answer)} 
                onChange={props.onChange}/>
            <label htmlFor={`${props.question} ${answer}`} className={`${answerStyle(answer)}`}>{fixText(answer)}</label>
        </div>))
```